# How to split a commit into sub commits without opening a new review in Gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

I am participating a open source project.
The project uses Gerrit code review system to check submitted codes.

Recently I've got a request to split the commit under review into smaller ones.
However, I cannot find out how to split commit without opening a new review.

Is there any way to split the commit under review?

Comment: In gerrit, one commit == one review.  If you are splitting up your commit you are, by definition, creating multiple reviews. Which is totally fine.

Comment: You could split one commit into a sequence of commits. One commit one review. Use Gerrit's feature `topic` to group them so that they must be submitted together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't split a commit in two without have another change (review). In Gerrit each commit corresponds to one independent change (review). This is not a issue, in fact this is a how things were designed to be in Gerrit where "code review" means to review every commit before it is accepted into the code base. Reviewing is much easier if the commits are as small as possible.

To understand better the Gerrit process, read the [Gerrit User Guide](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/intro-user.html) and [this example of working with Gerrit](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/intro-gerrit-walkthrough.html). I'm sure that things will become more clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
git rebase -i will do it.
```

To split apart your most recent commit, first:

```
$ git reset HEAD~
```

Now commit the pieces individually in the usual way, producing as many commits as you need.

If it was farther back in the tree, then

```
$ git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

where 3 is how many commits back it is.

If it was farther back in the tree than you want to count, then

```
$ git rebase -i 123abcd^
```

where 123abcd is the SHA1 of the commit you want to split up.

When you get the rebase edit screen, find the commit you want to break apart. At the beginning of that line, replace pick with edit (e for short). Save the buffer and exit. Rebase will now stop just after the commit you want to edit. Then:

```
$ git reset HEAD~
```

Commit the pieces individually in the usual way, producing as many commits as you need, then

```
$ git rebase --continue
```